# React Hook Form, Shadcn-Ui and Zod integration: Official Example giving error: Prop `id` did not match. Server

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form, react-typescript, next.js13, zod

I am trying to create forms with zod, zodResolver, react hook form and shadcn-ui, the official example given on the shadcn-ui docs, shows the following format, but when i try to create the minimal code I am getting error, again and again. Even i tried to install, re-install and read multiple resources from github, tyring example from others code. But, i am getting the same error. Also htmlFor label not working.

Minimal Reproducible code:

```
'use client'


import React from 'react'
import * as z from "zod"
import { zodResolver } from '@hookform/resolvers/zod' 
import {useForm} from "react-hook-form"
import { useState } from 'react'
import { Form, FormControl, FormField, FormItem, FormLabel } from '@/components/ui/form'
import { Input } from '@/components/ui/input'
import { Button } from '@/components/ui/button'


const formSchema = z.object({
    name:z.string().min(2)
})

type formType = z.infer<typeof formSchema>


function TestForm() {
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)
    const form = useForm<formType>({
        resolver:zodResolver(formSchema),
        defaultValues: {
            name:""
        },
    })

    const onSubmit =async (values:formType) => {
        console.log(values)
    }



  return (
    <div>
        <Form {...form}>
            <form onSubmit={form.handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
                <FormField
                    control={form.control}
                    name='name'
                    render={({field}) => (
                        <FormItem>
                            {/* <FormLabel>Name</FormLabel> */}
                            <FormControl>
                                <Input disabled={loading} placeholder='Test' {...field}/>
                            </FormControl>
                        </FormItem>
                    )}
                />
                <Button disabled={loading} type="submit">Submit</Button>


            </form>
            
        </Form>
    </div>
  )
}

export default TestForm
```

Error Obtained:

```
Warning: Prop `id` did not match. Server: ":R5mmmmcq:-form-item" Client: ":Rmqqqpj9:-form-item"
    at input
    at _c (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./components/ui/input.tsx:13:11)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/@radix-ui/react-slot/dist/index.mjs:46:23)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/@radix-ui/react-slot/dist/index.mjs:20:23)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./components/ui/form.tsx:124:14)
    at div
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./components/ui/form.tsx:74:11)
    at Controller (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/react-hook-form/dist/index.esm.mjs:544:37)
    at FormField (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./components/ui/form.tsx:29:14)
    at form
    at FormProvider (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/react-hook-form/dist/index.esm.mjs:180:13)
    at div
    at TestForm (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./app/(auth_)/login/test-form/page.tsx:26:82)
    at InnerLayoutRouter (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/layout-router.js:228:11)
    at RedirectErrorBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/redirect-boundary.js:73:9)
    at RedirectBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/redirect-boundary.js:81:11)
    at NotFoundBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/not-found-boundary.js:62:11)
    at LoadingBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/layout-router.js:325:11)
    at ErrorBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/error-boundary.js:104:11)
    at InnerScrollAndFocusHandler (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/layout-router.js:139:9)
    at ScrollAndFocusHandler (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/layout-router.js:214:11)
    at RenderFromTemplateContext (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/render-from-template-context.js:15:44)
    at OuterLayoutRouter (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/layout-router.js:335:11)
    at InnerLayoutRouter (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/layout-router.js:228:11)
    at RedirectErrorBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/redirect-boundary.js:73:9)
    at RedirectBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/redirect-boundary.js:81:11)
    at NotFoundBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/not-found-boundary.js:62:11)
    at LoadingBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/layout-router.js:325:11)
    at ErrorBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/error-boundary.js:104:11)
    at InnerScrollAndFocusHandler (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/layout-router.js:139:9)
    at ScrollAndFocusHandler (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/layout-router.js:214:11)
    at RenderFromTemplateContext (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/render-from-template-context.js:15:44)
    at OuterLayoutRouter (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/layout-router.js:335:11)
    at InnerLayoutRouter (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/layout-router.js:228:11)
    at RedirectErrorBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/redirect-boundary.js:73:9)
    at RedirectBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/redirect-boundary.js:81:11)
    at NotFoundBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/not-found-boundary.js:62:11)
    at LoadingBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/layout-router.js:325:11)
    at ErrorBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/error-boundary.js:104:11)
    at InnerScrollAndFocusHandler (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/layout-router.js:139:9)
    at ScrollAndFocusHandler (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/layout-router.js:214:11)
    at RenderFromTemplateContext (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/render-from-template-context.js:15:44)
    at OuterLayoutRouter (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/layout-router.js:335:11)
    at InnerLayoutRouter (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/layout-router.js:228:11)
    at RedirectErrorBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/redirect-boundary.js:73:9)
    at RedirectBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/redirect-boundary.js:81:11)
    at NotFoundBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/not-found-boundary.js:62:11)
    at LoadingBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/layout-router.js:325:11)
    at ErrorBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/error-boundary.js:104:11)
    at InnerScrollAndFocusHandler (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/layout-router.js:139:9)
    at ScrollAndFocusHandler (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/layout-router.js:214:11)
    at RenderFromTemplateContext (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/render-from-template-context.js:15:44)
    at OuterLayoutRouter (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/layout-router.js:335:11)
    at SessionProvider (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next-auth/react/index.js:455:24)
    at AuthProvider (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./app/(auth_)/providers/AuthProvider.tsx:11:11)
    at body
    at html
    at RedirectErrorBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/redirect-boundary.js:73:9)
    at RedirectBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/redirect-boundary.js:81:11)
    at NotFoundErrorBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/not-found-boundary.js:54:9)
    at NotFoundBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/not-found-boundary.js:62:11)
    at DevRootNotFoundBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/dev-root-not-found-boundary.js:32:11)
    at ReactDevOverlay (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/react-dev-overlay/internal/ReactDevOverlay.js:66:9)
    at HotReload (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/react-dev-overlay/hot-reloader-client.js:326:11)
    at Router (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/app-router.js:148:11)
    at ErrorBoundaryHandler (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/error-boundary.js:77:9)
    at ErrorBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/error-boundary.js:104:11)
    at AppRouter (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/app-router.js:396:13)
    at ServerRoot (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/app-index.js:166:11)
    at RSCComponent
    at ReactDevOverlay (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/react-dev-overlay/internal/ReactDevOverlay.js:66:9)
    at Root (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/app-index.js:183:11)
```

I tried multiple resources, updated the libs from npm latest, but same error keeps on popping, whenever input is added. As you can see from the above: the official example is used, as it is. But the results are still the same. Please help?

Comment: As per [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/shadcn-ui/ui/issues/1023) the library author notified this is fixed in canary version of next js but it is yet to be released stably.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and just installed the latest nextjs package which is 13.4.13.

`npm install next@latest react@latest react-dom@latest`

There is also a version downgrade option to 13.4.10.

After installing new version of next, you have to install new Eslint:

`npm install -D eslint-config-next@latest`

And then delete .next folder and when you run dev reload by Shift+F5 or Ctrl+Shift+R.

Additionally, there are two more solutions to this problem:

1. Add `from.watch()` before `onSubmit` function.
2. Remove `{...field}` and add `onChange={(e) => { field.onChange(e.target.value)}}`

Comment: installed eslint-config-next, it worked for me. Thanks man!